# Merging ILists to bind on datagridview to avoid using a database view

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

In the form we have this where IntaktsBudgetsType is a poorly named enum that only specifies wether to populate the datagridview after customer or product (You do the budgeting either after product or customer)

```
private void UpdateGridView() {

    bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = intaktsbudget.GetDataSource(this.comboBoxKundID.Text, IntaktsBudgetsType.PerKund);

    dataGridViewIntaktPerKund.DataSource = bs;
}
```

This populates the datagridview with a database view that merge the product, budget and customer tables.

The logic has the following method to get the correct set of IList from the repository which only does `GetTable<T>.ToList<T>`

```
public IEnumerable<IntaktsBudgetView> GetDataSource(string id, IntaktsBudgetsType type)
        {
            IList<IntaktsBudgetView> list = repository.SelectTable<IntaktsBudgetView>();

            switch (type)
            {   
                case IntaktsBudgetsType.PerKund:                            
                    return from i in list
                           where i.kundId == id
                           select i;
                case IntaktsBudgetsType.PerProdukt:                    
                    return from i in list
                           where i.produktId == id
                           select i;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Now I don't want to use a database view since that is read-only and I want to be able to perform CRUD actions on the datagridview.

I could build a class that acts as a wrapper for the whole thing and bind the different table values to class properties but that doesn't seem quite right since I would have to do this for every single thing that requires "the merge".

Something pretty important (and probably basic) is missing the the thought process but after spending a weekend on google and in books I give up and turn to the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

I do not exaclly see your problem. YOu can make a generic IList that supports an arary of ILists as constructor and basically exposes them merged. This runs down to a lot of plumbing code, but is very generic. THe IList only needs to track which original list every item is related to, so it can properly forward delete operations.

Comment: Im sorry but I don't really understand what you are suggesting. Could you update the answer with a snippet of code to explain?

Comment: Sadly not.  I have code for doing exactly that here, but it is about 10 pages long ;) Not complicated, though. it is called "BindingListView" and allows combining x lists input as well as filtering of exposed elements.

Comment: if size is only issue there are paste services such as Pastebin